# shell script to shutdown/restart Linux system

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any suitable shell script for shutting down or restarting a Linux machine? I have tried a shell script for shutdown, but when I enter `sudo shutdown` it will ask for the password. How we can enter the password using the script?

Comment: Entering a password using a script is generally a bad idea, since disclosure of the script (via e.g. sloppy permissions, insecure backup, etc.) can reveal your root password. Consider a different design - a daemon launched as `root` for example.

Comment: @Oldskool: Thanks for the information. But i want to shutdown machine using a shell script. for that we need to enter the passsword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the -S switch which reads the password from STDIN:

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

So to shut down the machine, your command would be like this (just replace `<password>` with your password):

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S poweroff
```

Exposing  your password is generally bad idea search for something that can protect / hide it. In the past I've used Jenkins plugins to do this while executing the scripts regularly.

Comment: @ Wald: can you please explain how we can shut down a linux machine using shell script ?

Comment: Like Wald said `$echo <password> | sudo -S reboot` or `$echo <password> | sudo -S poweroff`

Comment: Yup in the line I've provided above you simple have to change <password> to your password ( you can also echo a system variable although it isn't exactly hidden password but still maybe better than directly from a shell script. And you have to change <command> to what you want to execute from your sudo instead of simply doing "sudo" to login.

Comment: I would suggest to use string redirection as, at least, it will not be listed in the processes: `sudo -S <command> <<< password`

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX ye it's probably better but it still it would be best if he encrypts it with some other program.

Answer (score 8):

Another, in my opinion cleaner approach:

Create a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` with content:

```
%users ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
%users ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

This causes sudo to **not** ask for the password, if any user of group "users" tries to execute a shutdown or reboot. Of course you can also specify another group, maybe a newly created group for finer control of reboot permissions.

More information about the other possible settings for `sudo` can be found in the [Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

Comment: @ bratkartoffel :What should be the name of the file?

Comment: You can name it as you want, e.g. simply "reboot" or "powercontrol". More information can be found in the README file inside that directory.

Answer (score 1):

if you *really* want to achieve it, you should write a script containing the `shutdown` command; make `root` be its owner, then set the SUID bit with the `chmod` command and give to it executable permission for everybody. When executed, the owner of the script would become `root` and no password should be asked.

Comment: I like this approach. Can anyone verify that it works?

Comment: many operating systems ignore the setuid attribute when applied to executable shell scripts, for security. (Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid )