# Create shell script to reboot linux in case of incorrect shutdown

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi3

I have Raspbian Jessie 8 running in a Raspberry Pi 3. There are 3 JavaScript services that are automatically started by PM2.

However, if the Raspberry is shutdown incorrectly, e.g., if the energy cable is removed, the services don't start.

They only start automatically if the Raspberry is shutdown properly, e.g., using `sudo reboot`.

I need a shell script that checks if the Raspberry was incorrectly shutdown and, if it was, to be rebooted using `sudo reboot`.

I saw [here](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs-museum/3.0/LFS-BOOK-3.0-HTML/ch07-reboot.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863162/shell-script-to-shutdown-restart-linux-system) how to create a simple reboot script and [here](http://www.akamaras.com/linux/linux-script-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-and-start-it-if-its-stopped/) how to check if a service is running, but found nothing on how to check for an improper shutdown. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: *"... if the Raspberry is shutdown incorrectly, e.g., if the energy cable is removed, the services don't start"* - It sounds like the services or the service manager needs to be fixed.

Comment: It also sounds like a script that starts you javascript services if they aren't already started would be a better choice then rebooting merely to get your services to start. A reboot or a power cycle should start the services the same way... something feels off here.

Answer (score 1):

You can always put your services start in the legacy startup-file /etc/rc.local that is a shell script called as the very last thing in the startup. Make sure its executable.

Comment: I tried doing what you said, but the problem still persists. The services appear to start, but when I list them using `pm2 list` there are no running processes. If I shutdown the Raspberry properly, however, the processes are started via the `/etc/rc.local` file.